# Ionic2 Taking a Picture and Uploading it

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am working on a project with Ionic 2 and I want to upload image taken by camera. However, I cannot get it working.

I am using two plugin:

- Camera : cordova-plugin-camera (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)
- File-Transfer: cordova-plugin-file-transfer (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer)

EDIT: I am getting error code 1 which means file not found from file transfer plugin

I have tried with `this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI` with `this.fileURL` and it still gives me file not found error.

My code is below. Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated!

```
/* Take a picture with camera */
takePicture() {
    this.camera.getPicture({
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        correctOrientation: true
    }).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is a base64 encoded string
        this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        this.fileURL = imageData;
        this.images.push(this.base64Image);
        this.isPicture = 1;
        this.uploadPictures(this.fileURL);
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

/* Upload an image */
var fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    let options: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: "images",
        fileName: fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
        chunkedMode: true,
        mimeType: "image/jpeg",
        httpMethod: "POST",
    };

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Uploading...',
    });

    fileTransfer.upload(fileURL, encodeURI(this.API_URL+"api/order/receipt_pic/1491378111.3477"), options).then(data => {
        console.log('uploaded');
    }, err => {
        console.log('upload fail');
        console.log(err.code);
    });
}
```

Comment: "I cannot get it working".. can you be more specific? are you getting errors ?

Comment: What is the problem? any error?

Comment: `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` you have set this and are checking for filepath. Change to `destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL`

Comment: Sorry guys. I forget to mention the error. I have edited the content.

Comment: @suraj `destinationType` does not have FILE_URL according to document.

Answer (score 0):

Data_URL can be very heavy on the application and might cause it to crash if the image is high resolution.

**A working example for me:**

*to capture the pic*:

```
    var cameraOptions = {
          quality: 100,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
          allowEdit: false,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
          correctOrientation: true
        };

navigator.camera.getPicture(
  function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {
    uploadProfilePicture(imageUri)
    .then(function(data){

    },function(error){
      console.log('failed', error);
    });
}, function cameraError(error) {
  console.log('error', error);

}, cameraOptions);
```

*uploadProfilePicture(imageUri):*

```
  var url = BASE_URL+'/upload-avatar';
  var token = AuthService.getAccessToken(); 
  var options = {
    fileKey : "image", //this is the name of the param the server is expecting
    httpMethod: "POST",
    chunkedMode : true,
    mimeType : "image/jpeg",
    headers : {
      'Accept': 'application/json', //this is important
      'Authorization': token
    }
  };

var ft = new FileTransfer();
  ft.upload(imageUri, encodeURI(url), win, fail, options);
  function win (){
  }
  function fail (){
  }
```

Since you are using `httpMethod: "POST"` , you need to append `headers` to the option object. 
the `'Accept': 'application/json'` is what worked for me and i also send the token since the user must be authenticated to upload a pic.